# Google Bigquery says "Billing has not been enabled for this project."

Tags: billing, google-bigquery

I'm trying to load data in a new BigQuery table, but when I run the following in the 'bq shell'

> load ct.ads /tmp/data.csv  id:integer,source:string,clicks:integer

I get

Waiting on job_7e1d39b261d041da8674a769e8275b91 ... (0s) Current status: DONE
BigQuery error in load operation: Billing has not been enabled for this project.

I've enabled billing and the tab in Google Api Console says:

---

Your billing information may take a few minutes to update. Please refresh this page for updates.

Authorized by:  martin@foo.com - you
Unbilled usage (estimate, updated daily)
Start date  May 2, 2012
Total (before taxes)    0.00 USD
Statements
None

---

Any hints?

---

Ok, it seems when I entered the CC information it was refused; I tried with another CC and it seems to be fine...

Now it says:

---

### Billing is enabled for all active, billable services

tnx

Comment: i'm having the same problem. I set up billing, but BigQuery doesn't think so (yet?)

Comment: 14 hours later, and I still can't create a dataset because of this problem. Its not the cache (or it has a VERY slow eviction schedule)

Comment: rbp -- can you let us know your project id?

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery caches billing state, it may take a few hours to be updated. When did you fix the CC number? If it was today, it may just not have been updated in the cache. If it takes more than 8 hours or so, please let us know and we'll investigate.

Comment: a few hour delay violates the Principle of Least Astonishment

Comment: Has this been fixed ? It seems that I have the same issue. Even after waiting 24 hours.

Comment: what is your project id?